# Как в строке убрать оставить один знак после запятой

Tags: java, строки, float

Начал писать код, в массив float генерируются числа, после чего этот массив превращается в String, столкнулся с проблемой, требуется при выводе строки оставить один знак после запятой, если честно пытался что-то найти в интернете, но как то не получилось, может что подскажете?

```java
public class Hospital {

    public static float[] generatePatientsTemperatures(int patientsCount) {

        float[] array;
        array = new float[30];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = ((float)( Math.random() * (40-32)) + 32);
            System.out.println( array[i]);
            var a = array[i];
        }


        return array;
    }

    public static String getReport(float[] temperatureData) {


        float[] massiv = Hospital.generatePatientsTemperatures (0);

        float average = 0;
        float sum = 0;
        if (massiv.length > 0){
            for (int i = 0; i < massiv.length; i++) {

                sum += massiv[i];
                average = sum/massiv.length;
                average = Math.round (average);
            }
        }
        ////Превратив в список
        String temperatursPathients = Arrays.toString(massiv);
        temperatursPathients = temperatursPathients.replaceAll (",","");
        ////Вычисляем количество здоровых пациентов
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < massiv.length; i++) {
            if (massiv[i] > 36.6 && massiv[i] < 36.8) {
                System.out.println(massiv[i]);
                count++;
            }
        }
        String report =
                "Температуры пациентов: "  + temperatursPathients +
                        "\nСредняя температура: " + average +
                        "\nКоличество здоровых: " + count;

        return report;
    }
}
```

Comment: ну так либо округлить либо вывести каким-нить методом форматирования с `%.1f`

Answer (score 0):

1. Найти позицию запятой в строке. `string.indexOf(",")`
2. Взять подстроку от начала до запятой плюс 1.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, все было намного проще

```
array[i] = (float)(Math.round(array[i] * 10.0)/10.0);
```

оставляет ровно один знак после запятой в массиве